# Unable to use sudo command (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)

Tags: permissions, sudo

When I type sudo on terminal, I get:

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

More info:

```
ls -ld / /etc /etc/sudoers
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Dez 21 22:44 /
drw-rw-r-x 162 root root 12288 Jan 18 15:13 /etc
-r--r-----   1 root root   746 Jan 18 14:21 /etc/sudoers
```

`pkexec visudo`:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: I don't know if it's significant but your `/etc` permissions look messed up - the default is `drwxr-xr-x` AFAIK (executable permission is needed in order to traverse directories).

Comment: @EliahKagan why don't you post an answer - since you've done the heavy lifting ;)

Comment: ... aaand upvoted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Run `pkexec chmod 755 /etc` to fix this.

As [steeldriver suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873430/unable-to-use-sudo-command-ubuntu-16-04-1-lts#comment1355774_873430), this error is because `/etc` has the wrong permissions. The permissions shown from `ls -ld /etc` *should* look like:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

But yours look like:

```
drw-rw-r-x
```

This is preventing `sudo` from traversing `/etc` to access `/etc/sudoers`.

The "permission denied" error message just trying to retrieve metadata on (i.e., to stat) a file nearly always means the file is missing or directories leading to it cannot be traversed, and when you ran `ls` on the file, it was shown to exist.

I have tested this (on a virtual machine) by breaking permissions on `/etc` with `chmod ug-x`, and was able to produce your exact error message. (You *shouldn't* run `chmod` with `ug-x` on it -- that's how I deliberately *broke* the permissions, not how to fix them.)

**To fix the permissions on `/etc`**, give the user and group owners executable permissions. The absence of those permissions is the cause of this problem. In addition, by default `/etc` doesn't need the group owner to be given write permissions, so unless you *know* you want this, I recommend changing that back too.

This command will reset `/etc` to the default permissions:

```
pkexec chmod 755 /etc
```

That should work for you since you were able to run other commands as root with `pkexec`. Other users who find this by searching will usually be able to fix it the same way, but for systems without `pkexec` (or where `pkexec` will not work) it may be necessary to boot into recovery mode or from a live CD/DVD/USB to fix the permissions. *You* shouldn't need to do that, though. Just run that one simple command, and `sudo` should work again.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps, as this method worked for me

If you are not able to open your file through,

```
sudo vi /etc/sudoers
```

At first, you should provide permissions as given above by [Eliah][1] and also,

```
pkexec chmod 755 /etc
```

Then, try to open the sudoers file using

```
pkexec vi /etc/sudoers
```

Edit your changes then save and exit.
Try the sudo command now,

```
sudo apt update
```

Hope this helps.